# I want to open html files in a directory folder sequentially, parse information by using beautifulsoup and save it as a csv file

Tags: python, csv, beautifulsoup

At first, i tried to open just a file named 'index.html', parse it and saved it as a csv file. This was the code and it worked well. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CacN1.png)

```
with open('/Users/kwon/Downloads/cnn/index.html') as html_file:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_file, 'html.parser')

cnn_file = open('cnn2.csv', 'w')
cnn_writer = csv.writer(cnn_file)
cnn_writer.writerow(['filename','date','headline','text'])

filename = 'index000'
print(filename)

date = soup.find(class_='update-time').text
date = date.split(' ')[5]+' '+date.split(' ')[6]+' '+date.split(' ')[7]
print(date)

headline = soup.title.text
headline = headline.split('-')[0]
print(headline)

txt = soup.find(class_="zn zn-body-text zn-body zn--idx-0 zn--ordinary zn-has-multiple-containers zn-has-r'\d*'-containers").text 
print(txt) 

cnn_writer.writerow([filename, date, headline, txt])
cnn_file.close()
```

But i want to iterate the same process for all html files(index.html~index591.html) in a directory folder. So i started by using glob module to open files sequentially. Then, tried 'for loop' to parse as i did before. Somehow i don't know how to read and parse them sequentially and name filename as 'index000' to 'index591'. Also if i run the code below i get the error saying 'find() takes no keyword arguments'.

```
import glob    
path = '/Users/kwon-yejin/Downloads/cnn2/*.html'   
files=glob.glob(path) 
for file in files:
    html = open(file, 'r')
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

for line in soup:
    filename = 'index000'
    print(filename)

    date = line.find(class_='update-time').text
    date = date.split(' ')[5]+' '+date.split(' ')[6]+' '+date.split(' ')[7]
    print(date)

    headline = line.title.text
    headline = headline.split('-')[0]
    print(headline)

    txt = line.find(class_="zn zn-body-text zn-body zn--idx-0 zn--ordinary zn-has-multiple-containers zn-has-21-containers").text 
    print(txt)
```

Comment: filename is a string so use string functions like `"index{:03}".format(number)` - https://pyformat.info . And use `for number, file in enumerate(files):`

Comment: maybe you should use only one `for`-loop` and not use `for line in soup`

Comment: maybe you assigned normal string to `line` and `string.find()` doesn't use `class_`

Comment: Thanks for comments. I will fix it as you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Sread and parse them sequentially filename as 'index000' to 'index591'

```
path = '/Users/kwon-yejin/Downloads/cnn2/'

for i in range(592):
    file = path+'index'+str(i).zfill(3)+'.html'
    print(file)

        /Users/kwon-yejin/Downloads/cnn2/index000.html
        /Users/kwon-yejin/Downloads/cnn2/index001.html
        /Users/kwon-yejin/Downloads/cnn2/index002.html
        /Users/kwon-yejin/Downloads/cnn2/index003.html
        ..................
        /Users/kwon-yejin/Downloads/cnn2/index589.html
        /Users/kwon-yejin/Downloads/cnn2/index590.html
        /Users/kwon-yejin/Downloads/cnn2/index591.html
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I changed 'filename' in the for loop by using code above. But since i have files named 'index.html', 'index1.html', 'index2.html', .... , 'index591.html', i'm not sure whether the code you suggested can read files sequentially. So i just used glob module instead. Would it be alright?